# Pattern match a Seq with Range

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Consider a piece of code:

```
def foo(xs: Seq[Int]) = xs match {
  case Nil => "empty list"
  case head :: Nil => "one element list"
  case head :: tail => s"head is $head and tail is $tail"
}

val x1 = Seq(1,2,3)
println(foo(x1))

val x2 = Seq()
println(foo(x2))

val x3 = Seq(1)
println(foo(x3))

val problem = 1 to 10
println(foo(problem))
```

A problem occurs, when we try to match a Range in `foo(problem)`.

`scala.MatchError: Range(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10) (of class scala.collection.immutable.Range$Inclusive)`.

Converting Range to Seq with `val problem = (1 to 10).toSeq` is useless, as the `toSeq` method just returns the Range itself:

`override def toSeq = this`.

A workaround can be used:

`val problem = (1 to 10).toList.toSeq`,

but it's not exactly the prettiest thing I've seen.

What is the proper way to match a Range to [head:tail] pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `+:` operator.  It's like `::`, except instead of only being for List, it works on any Seq.

```
def foo(xs: Seq[Int]) = xs match {
  case Seq() => "empty list"
  case head +: Seq() => "one element list"
  case head +: tail => s"head is $head and tail is $tail"
}
```

Or, even better, just pattern match on the `Seq` extractor:

```
def foo(xs: Seq[Int]) = xs match {
  case Seq() => "empty list"
  case Seq(head) => "one element list"
  case Seq(head, tail @ _*) => s"head is $head and tail is $tail"
}
```